# Slow Connection to SQL Server using OleDB

Tags: sql-server-2008, isapi

I have a web application using an ISAPI filter (written in c\c++) and OleDB to connect to a SQL Server 2008.  The application works fine on a certain number of Windows Server 2008 R2.

Recently I found another server, also Windows 2008 R2, where the application is really slow.
I wrote a simple console application using C# and OleDB and I found it is really slow when executing a simple query like `SELECT GETDATE()`.  I figured out that the something is wrong at the OleDB level, but I'm now stuck.

SQL Server is installed on a different server on the same subnet and there are no firewalls between the Web Server and SQL Server.

My test environment was:
S1: server 2008 (64bit)
S2: server 2008 (64bit)
S3: server 2003 (32bit)

all servers were running SQL Server 2008 and are on the same network (using a switch)
I ran my C# application executing SELECT GETDATE() in the following configuration (the first server is where the C# app is running, the second is where SQL SERVER is)

S1 -> S1 <1ms
S1 -> S3 5ms
S1 -> S2 300ms
S2 -> S2 <1ms

Any idea on how to proceed in the investigation?

Comment: What is slow to you?  What is it you figured out at the OleDB level?  Where exactly are you stuck?  A bit more detail would help you get the answers you need.

Comment: @TylerShads
My test environment was:  
S1: server 2008 (64bit)  
S2: server 2008 (64bit)  
S3: server 2003 (32bit)  

all servers were running SQL Server 2008 and are on the same network (using a switch)   

I ran my C# application executing SELECT GETDATE() in the following configuration (the first server is where the C# app is running, the second is where SQL SERVER is)

S1 -> S1  <1ms
S1 -> S3   5ms
S1 -> S2 300ms
S2 -> S2  <1ms

Comment: Now add that to your question instead of a comment :)